# wordpress Get all media from a category

Tags: wordpress

Is there function like get_attached_media but for categories?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media

I've  assigned my images categories with:

> function wptp_add_categories_to_attachments() {
>      register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
>   }
>   add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_categories_to_attachments' );

And all I need to do is to list images in a category.

Edit:
To clarify, I have my category page which has tabs, one listing articles, one listing some category taxonomy informations and one which will display a list of images.
These images are assigned to the category but I do not know the function to pull the list of images from the category.

Comment: Do you mean get all attachments from all the posts under a category?

Comment: No only the ones I tagged (selected a category for). As a matter of fact in my case most of these images wouldn't be attached in a post.

Comment: Still don't understand the question. Let's see if anyone will be able to help. Otherwise you should make it clear.

Comment: Let me try to clarify in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get attachments just like any other type of post. So,

```
$args = array(
    'category' => $cat_ID or
    'category_name' => $cat_name,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
```